# Error when trying to cast from System.Double to System.Single

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am sure this will turn out to be something simple. I have the following Silverlight 4 C# code:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
r.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 150f);
r.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 50f);
r.Width = 100;
r.Height = 100;

LayoutRoot.Children.Add(r);
```

For some reason, when I run my application, it is getting an error on the SetValue lines. The error I am getting is:

```
Uncaught Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application DependencyProperty of type System.Double cannot be set on an object of type System.Single.
```

I tried to cast implicitly to Single, but still got the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in a boxed float, and the rectangle is then trying to unbox it to a double. Just pass in doubles to start with, and it should be fine:

```
r.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 150d);
r.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 50d);
```

Note that [`Canvas.Left`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.left.aspx) and [`Canvas.Top`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.top.aspx) are of type `double`, not `float`.

Comment: Jon, thanks for the catch. The prefix went right over my head for some reason. Didn't even notice I was floating it. This solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These properties have type double. You are passing single precision values, floats. Pass doubles and all will be well.